# How do I iterate over an array with #each in hbs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, iteration

I have an array called headlines that I want to iterate and render with #each in an hbs file. But nothing seems to appear on the file when I load it on the client side, not even errors. Where am I going wrong?

```
<body>

         {{#each headlines}}

         <h1> {{this}} </h1>

         {{/each}}

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo:

```js
const templateInput = {
  headlines: [ "bar", "foo", "bar2", "foo2"]
};

const setup = () => {
    const personTemplate = document.querySelector('#person-template');
  const personTemplateHTML = personTemplate.innerHTML;
  const template = Handlebars.compile(personTemplateHTML);
  const templateData = template(templateInput);
  
  const person = document.querySelector('#person');
  person.innerHTML = templateData;
}

//loéd
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handlebars@latest/dist/handlebars.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="person"></section>
  <script id="person-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each headlines}}
    <h1> {{this}} </h1>
  {{/each}}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I do wonder why you need handlebars. With template-literals is easily achievable without this plugin. An example: https://jsfiddle.net/51j4xd6o/